# How to calculate identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How to determine an identity matrix with or without using system of equations?
Let's say I have this matrix, and I have this system of equations;
$$
A =
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & c   \\
d & e & f  \\
g & h & i \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

$$A  I = A$$
We know that
$$ I = \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
j & k & l  \\
m & n & o  \\
p & q & r \\
\end{array}
\right]$$

so that by multiplying matrices we get this system of equations
\begin{cases} aj + bm + pc = a \\ ak + bn + cq = b \\ al + bo + cr = c \\ dj + em + fp = d \\dk + en + fq = e \\ dl + eo + fr = f \\ gj + hm + pi = g \\kg + hn + iq = h \\ gl + ho + ir = i \end{cases}

Solving all of them is hard, how should I approach this problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the matrix $I$?

Answer (score 0):

In general there could be infinite solutions to the problem, just consider $A=0$.

But if the matrix $A$ was invertible, the the only solution is $I=\mathbb{1}$ as $$AI=A\implies I=A^{-1}A=\mathbb{1}.$$

Comment: Your argument is circular. If you don't know what $I$ is, you don't know what $A^{-1}$ is or if it is unique. The standard proof for the uniqueness of the identity is $e_1 = e_1e_2 = e_2$ and doesn't assume the existence of inverses (because that only makes sense once you settled the uniqueness of the identity).

Comment: No. I think the OP wants to prove that if $AB=A$ then $B$ is the identity, which obviously is wrong in general. What I am saying is that if $A$ was invertible then what the OP is claiming would hold.

Comment: If that is what he is asking, yes. I guess the OP is not very clear...

Comment: I don't understand how there can be inifinite identity matrices? In my textbook there's only one. Sorry for being newbie I'm just starting

Comment: No, there is just one identity matrix. The problem here is that the definition of identity matrix is that for all matrices $A$ you have $AI=A$ and not for a single one. Now that you know this, you can choose elementary matrices (where all entries are $0$ but for a single $1$) and you will get a system of many equations whose only solution will be the identity matrix with only ones on the diagonal.